# Configure HikariCP for Eclipselink JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, hikaricp

my recent a few projects are built on eclipselink/jpa/jsf structure. I wanted to use HikariCP as data source. So far I searched and found out that all examples/tutorials about HikariCP is based on Spring and Hibarnate. Is there any way to use HikariCP as my main data source? How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Here is my data source class:

```
public enum EntityManagerFactoryDS {

    public final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    EntityManagerFactoryDS() {
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "driver");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "url"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user"));
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password"));
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql", properties);
    }

    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getInstance() {
        return emf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your application deployed? In GlassFish?

Comment: @Simon no, in Tomcat.

Comment: Then you should use a datasource: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial#Install_the_Tomcat_6_Web_Container and then you can use HikariCP in the datasource https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.)

Comment: If I deploy my application on OpenShift, how can I configure HikariCP in my application? as mine is a standalone spring boot application using eclipseLink JPA. Please let me know as I'm not finding any articles explaining on how to configure.

Comment: @kuti here is the gist I have created https://gist.github.com/objectorientedperson/7ac9ff57fa263b1c2640f62b45955e49